# Trouble with Tomcat 7 64 bit options

Tags: 64-bit, tomcat

i'm having some trouble running TeamCity on Windows 7 64bit, with tomcat 7 and Java 1.7.
When putting some of the recomended settings in the service control panel:

> -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

i always get the following messages:

```
[2012-11-30 12:39:48] [error] CreateJavaVM Failed
[2012-11-30 12:39:48] [error] Can not find the environment option that was specified.
[2012-11-30 12:39:48] [error] Failed to start Java
[2012-11-30 12:39:48] [error] ServiceStart returned
```

(translated from italian)
Anyone encountered some similar problem?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of where exactly you're adding those parameters? Also, have you tried adding them one by one till it fails, to see if you can pinpoint the offending one?